# Using jsoup in android

Tags: android, html, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to use Jsoup 1.8.1 in android to parse HTML in this URL- http://sirim.co.il/.

For some reason, I can't get it to work.. the methods that work in other websites don't work here.

Is there something wrong in my code? or with the website?

just trying to get all the tables from the website and add to TextView their id's.. 
the TextView is empty.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://sirim.co.il/").get();
Elements metaElems = doc.select("table");
for (Element metaElem : metaElems) {
// for every "table" tag, get the id attribute
        String id = metaElem.attr("id");
        buffer.append(id + "\r\n");
}

httpInfo.setText(s); // set text of TextView
```

any ideas ot help?
thanks

**EDIT:** the code is simple as can be.
for some reason it works in java but doesn't work in android

The metaElems is empty, I guess it is not even getting the elements..
ideas?

```
    getRecipes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // new ParseURL().execute(new String[] { URL });
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            Document doc;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://sirim.co.il/").get();
                Elements metaElems = doc.select("table");
                for (Element metaElem : metaElems) {
                    // for every "table" tag, get the id attribute
                    String id = metaElem.attr("id");
                    buffer.append(id);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            httpInfo.setText(buffer.toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: did you try logging the s ??

Comment: What is metaElems.length? Are you getting elements in the first place

Comment: the MetaElems in empty.. See my Update on the question for thecode

Comment: Check my edit. You are probably getting this because you perform a network request on the UI thread.

Comment: I tried to do it already.. Same result, I just posted it like that so it would be simpler. The weird thing is that it does work perfectly in java but not in android

Answer (score 2):

That code works for me (plain java) - prints all the ids of tables (when id is not set, a blank line is printed):

```
package jsoup;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://sirim.co.il/").get();
            Elements metaElems = doc.select("table");
            for (Element metaElem : metaElems) {
            // for every "table" tag, get the id attribute
                    String id = metaElem.attr("id");
                    System.out.println(id);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT**: You are probably getting this because you are sending a network request in the UI thread. Offload the request to a [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) doInBackground..

See: [Use Jsoup in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651438/use-jsoup-in-android)

Comment: thanks for your answer. it works for me in java as well, and in android it just doesn't... see my update in the question for the code now

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work!
It was because the user agant from the mobile is not the same as the user agent from the desktop application.

I just changed it like in this link - http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2013/01/29/a-note-when-using-jsoup-user-agent/